# Can ASCII code for a char be printed in C++ like in C?

Tags: c++, c, ascii, printf

As we can print the ASCII code and increment it in C
--> e.g:

```
{
char ch='A';
ch++;
printf("%d",ch); 
}
```

this will output "66" on the console.

How can this be done in C++ ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just cast it to an `int` before you output it, so that it isn't interpreted as a character:

```
char ch = 'A';
ch++;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(ch);
```

Note, however, that this isn't guaranteed to output the value corresponding to the character `'B'`. If your execution character set is ASCII or some other sane character set, then it will be, but there is no guarantee from the standard about your execution character set (other than the numerical digit characters, `0` to `9`, having consecutive values).

Answer (score 4):

`printf` will work just like that in C++.  But if you want to use `cout`, you just need to cast:

```
char ch = 'A';
ch++;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

No cast needed:

```
{
char ch='A';
ch++;
std::cout << ch << ": " << +ch << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Using the unary `+` causes an implicit conversion to `int`, right?  Is that better than an explicit cast?

Comment: @CarlNorum - right. "better" is a matter of taste. I suspect most people would prefer an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done the exact same way in C++:

```
{
char ch='A';
ch++;
printf("%d",ch); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the fact that neither C nor C++ insist on the *encoding* being ASCII (although it's ubiquitous on desktop computers), the code you present is valid C++.

In many (although by no means all) respects, C++ is a superset of C.

Comment: FYI: The first C++ compilers were translators that converted the C++ source code into C and then compiled - compiler messages were a _joy_.  So at that time C did everything C++ did and more, though not as elegantly.